# Curl отправка большого файла

Tags: curl

Есть необходимость отправки zip архивов чистым curl.
Образец:

```
curl -v --data-binary @FILE.zip -H 'Content-Type: application/zip' http://HOST:PORT/dir/date/FILE.zip
```

все отработало как надо, но при загрузки файла 4,7 GB выдает:

```
curl: option --data-binary: out of memory
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

очевидный вопрос - как исправить? спасибо за внимание

Comment: подозреваю что вам может помочь только переход на x64 версию(если она существует), либо грузить частями(если это не поможет).
Но это лишь подозрение основанное на размере файла и особенностей 32х разрядных ОС\ПО

Comment: да, мне известно о особенностях 32х, стоит 64. И, к сожалению, есть необходимость не разбивать файл.

Comment: глянул исходник — `curl` всегда читает свои данные полностью т.к. ему нужно знать размер наперёд... так что средствами бинарника похоже этого ни как не сделать... можно или свою утилитку на Си написать или воспользоваться биндингами curl'а для какого-нить скриптового языка...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793166/4496422, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222806/4496422

Comment: да... был неправ.... просмотрел `-T`...

Comment: curl -XPOST -T big-file.iso https://example.com 
выход, всем спасибо